# Prove that if $A\triangle B = C\triangle B$, then $A = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am working with proofs in discrete math.
Help to prove:

For the sets $A$ and $B$, we define the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ to be $A \triangle  B = (A-B)\cup(B-A).$

Prove that if $A \triangle B = C \triangle B,$ then $A = C.$

Comment: You really should learn some basic $\LaTeX$...

Comment: Let's try to be constructive, @tomasz.

Comment: @vadim123: check this link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117 (pasted vanilla from the faq)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\in A$.

1. If $a\in B$, then $a\notin A\triangle B$.  Hence $a\notin C\triangle B$.  Since $a\in B$ we must have $a\in C$.
2. On the other hand, if $a\notin B$, then $a\in A\triangle B=C\triangle B$.  Since $a\notin B$, we must have $a\in C$.

Therefore $A\subseteq C$, and by symmetry $A=C$.

Answer (score 1):

Calculationally,
$$
\begin{align}
& A \Delta B = C \Delta B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\Delta$, twice; extensionality"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \;\equiv\; x \in C \not\equiv x \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"extensionality"} \\
& A = C \\
\end{align}
$$