# Prove that $A \triangle B=B\triangle C\implies A=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $A \triangle B=B\triangle C\implies A=C$

We have
$A \triangle B=B\triangle C\implies A=C\\
\implies (A\cap B')\cup (B\cap A') = (B\cap C')\cup (C\cap B') $
How can I proceed for the result?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382773/prove-that-if-a-triangle-b-c-triangle-b-then-a-c?rq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296112/prove-that-if-a-mathbin-triangle-c-b-mathbin-triangle-c-then-a-b?rq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537172/a-oplus-b-a-oplus-c-imply-b-c

Comment: @FourierTransform thank you very much. This link is helpful

Comment: You're welcome!